# Search Macro Not Returning All Results

Tags: excel, vba

Hello and thank you for your time.

I have a listbox that is populated by searching spreadsheet data.
The list box is only populating my intended return at the top most row only.
The rest of the data for row 2 of column 2 of the listbox onward does not populate.

I have tried different offset numbers in the row number,column offset and adding more .listcounts. I have tried changing the last most listcount ending digit to 0 and after the error the listbox was correctly populated but only to a unknown amount of rows.

I may be wrong but i imagine this is something to do with the loop?

Is there a better way to this kind of task?
[Data Range Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Gu6.jpg) 
[Results Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK1DK.jpg)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range    
Dim ws As Worksheet   
Dim i As Integer    
Set ws = ActiveSheet    
Set rng = ws.Range("A:E")    
Set fnd = rng.Find(TextBox1)    
If fnd Is Nothing Then MsgBox txtSearch & " not found": Exit Sub    
Set first = fnd   
With ListBox1    
.Clear    
.AddItem fnd.Offset(, -4)    
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(, 0)    
Do    
Set fnd = rng.FindNext(fnd)    
If fnd.Address = first.Address Then Exit Do    
.AddItem fnd.Offset(, -4)    
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(, 1)    
Loop    
End With  
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you have a loop here.  The syntax is either Do While or Do Until.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a loop here.  Your Do... Loop is missing a While or Until statement.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/do-loop-statement for how to use a Do... Loop statement. It should be something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range    
Dim ws As Worksheet   
Dim i As Integer    
Set ws = ActiveSheet    
Set rng = ws.Range("A:E")    
Set fnd = rng.Find(TextBox1)    
If fnd Is Nothing Then MsgBox txtSearch & " not found": Exit Sub    
Set first = fnd   
With ListBox1    
.Clear    
.AddItem fnd.Offset(, -4)    
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(, 0)    
Do    
Set fnd = rng.FindNext(fnd)    
If fnd.Address = first.Address Then Exit Do    
.AddItem fnd.Offset(, -4)    
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(, 1)    
Loop Until 'your logic here'
End With  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Macro

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim adrs1$, Actual_adrs$
ListBox1.Clear
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("A:E")
Set fnd = rng.Find(TextBox1.Value)
If fnd Is Nothing Then MsgBox TextBox1.Value & " not found": Exit Sub
 Actual_adrs = fnd.Address: adrs1 = Actual_adrs

Do
    With ListBox1
    .AddItem fnd.Offset(, -4)
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(, 0)
    End With

    Set fnd = rng.FindNext(fnd)
     Actual_adrs = fnd.Address
    If Actual_adrs = adrs1 Then Exit Do
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mention, your loop logic is incorrect. I think this should work for you. I changed up the spacing, but it's mostly the same macro with just a `Do While` at the start of your loop.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, first As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("A:E")
    Set fnd = rng.Find(TextBox1)


    If fnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox txtSearch & " not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set first = fnd
    With ListBox1
        .Clear
        .AddItem fnd.Offset(, -4)
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(, 0)

        'second find needs to be out of the loop
        Set fnd = rng.FindNext(fnd)

        Do While fnd.Address <> first.Address

            .AddItem fnd.Offset(, -4)
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(, 1)

            Set fnd = rng.FindNext(fnd)
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi all. Thank you so much for your response. I will go back and introduce your suggestions to the code. I appreciate your time.  I feel i have learned from all the answers provided. I hope i can answer a question like this in the future.